# JRuby: nil != nil: RSpec tests fail even though arrays are the same

Tags: rspec, jruby

I am seeing an issue in JRuby where my rspec specs fail even though the expected and actual output are the same.  Here is the failure message:

```
Failures:

  1) PgArrayParser#parse_pg_array one dimensional arrays NULL values returns an array of strings, with nils replacing NULL characters
     Failure/Error: parser.parse_pg_array(%[{1,NULL,NULL}]).should eq ['1',nil,nil]

       expected: ["1", nil, nil]
            got: ["1", nil, nil]

       (compared using ==)

       Diff:["1", nil, nil].==(["1", nil, nil]) returned false even though the diff between ["1", nil, nil] and ["1", nil, nil] is empty. Check the implementation of ["1", nil, nil].==.
     # ./spec/parser_spec.rb:26:in `(root)'

  2) PgArrayParser#parse_pg_array two dimensional arrays strings returns an array of strings with a sub array and a quoted }
     Failure/Error: parser.parse_pg_array(%[{1,{"2,}3",NULL},4}]).should eq ['1',['2,}3',nil],'4']

       expected: ["1", ["2,}3", nil], "4"]
            got: ["1", ["2,}3", nil], "4"]

       (compared using ==)

       Diff:["1", ["2,}3", nil], "4"].==(["1", ["2,}3", nil], "4"]) returned false even though the diff between ["1", ["2,}3", nil], "4"] and ["1", ["2,}3", nil], "4"] is empty. Check the implementation of ["1", ["2,}3", nil], "4"].==.
     # ./spec/parser_spec.rb:69:in `(root)'

  3) PgArrayParser#parse_pg_array three dimensional arrays returns an array of strings with sub arrays
     Failure/Error: parser.parse_pg_array(%[{1,{2,{3,4}},{NULL,6},7}]).should eq ['1',['2',['3','4']],[nil,'6'],'7']

       expected: ["1", ["2", ["3", "4"]], [nil, "6"], "7"]
            got: ["1", ["2", ["3", "4"]], [nil, "6"], "7"]

       (compared using ==)

       Diff:["1", ["2", ["3", "4"]], [nil, "6"], "7"].==(["1", ["2", ["3", "4"]], [nil, "6"], "7"]) returned false even though the diff between ["1", ["2", ["3", "4"]], [nil, "6"], "7"] and ["1", ["2", ["3", "4"]], [nil, "6"], "7"] is empty. Check the implementation of ["
1", ["2", ["3", "4"]], [nil, "6"], "7"].==.
     # ./spec/parser_spec.rb:87:in `(root)'

Finished in 0.2 seconds
15 examples, 3 failures
```

Using `=~` instead of `eq` or `==` yielded the following output:

```
..F.......F..F.

Failures:

  1) PgArrayParser#parse_pg_array one dimensional arrays NULL values returns an array of strings, with nils replacing NULL characters
     Failure/Error: parser.parse_pg_array(%[{1,NULL,NULL}]).should =~ ['1',nil,nil]
       expected collection contained:  ["1", nil, nil]
       actual collection contained:    ["1", nil, nil]
       the missing elements were:      [nil, nil]
       the extra elements were:        [nil, nil]
     # ./spec/parser_spec.rb:26:in `(root)'

  2) PgArrayParser#parse_pg_array two dimensional arrays strings returns an array of strings with a sub array and a quoted }
     Failure/Error: parser.parse_pg_array(%[{1,{"2,}3",NULL},4}]).should =~ ['1',['2,}3',nil],'4']
       expected collection contained:  ["1", ["2,}3", nil], "4"]
       actual collection contained:    ["1", ["2,}3", nil], "4"]
       the missing elements were:      [["2,}3", nil]]
       the extra elements were:        [["2,}3", nil]]
     # ./spec/parser_spec.rb:69:in `(root)'

  3) PgArrayParser#parse_pg_array three dimensional arrays returns an array of strings with sub arrays
     Failure/Error: parser.parse_pg_array(%[{1,{2,{3,4}},{NULL,6},7}]).should =~ ['1',['2',['3','4']],[nil,'6'],'7']
       expected collection contained:  ["1", ["2", ["3", "4"]], [nil, "6"], "7"]
       actual collection contained:    ["1", ["2", ["3", "4"]], [nil, "6"], "7"]
       the missing elements were:      [[nil, "6"]]
       the extra elements were:        [[nil, "6"]]
     # ./spec/parser_spec.rb:87:in `(root)'

Finished in 0.17 seconds
15 examples, 3 failures
```

The specs are [here](https://github.com/dockyard/pg_array_parser/blob/jruby-compatibility/spec/parser_spec.rb). The thing to note is that these comparisons are the only ones that contain `nil`s. It seems like a `nil` instantiated in Java is not the same as a `nil` in JRuby Does anyone know of a work around for this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `runtime.getNil()` instead of `new RubyNil(runtime)` [here](https://github.com/dockyard/pg_array_parser/blob/77c3f727bc8eafcbf636d7a06c16623ba893ed54/ext/pg_array_parser/PgArrayParserEngine.java#L62).

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to match the arrays using =~? for example:

```
[1,2,3].should =~ [1,2,3]
```

I had a problem matching arrays some days ago and this worked fine for me.